# NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: returns nil in init: method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

**Update**: This works if I call archiveRootObject: from applicationDidFinishLaunching:. If I call it from the init: method of a singleton class, it returns nil.

I'm very confused by the behavior of NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:. [The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/unarchiveObjectWithFile:) says that it will return nil if the file doesn't exist. With one of my objects, the following happens:

```
Game *g1 = [Game getGame];
NSString *archivePath = [Game getArchivePath];
bool success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:g1 toFile:archivePath];
Game *g2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];

// success is true, g2 is nil
```

I've verified that the file actually does exist and is getting written to by the archiveRootObject: method. What am I doing wrong preventing me from getting a Game object back out of the archive?

Comment: I doubt this will solve your question, but in Objective-C the proper term is `BOOL` instead of `bool`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is my first Objective-C project. I've updated all my bool's to BOOL's.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at objc_exception_throw and see if an exception is being raised.

Comment: @Algorithmic Did you ever find the solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

I've meet the same trouble in Xcode 4.1 with ARC support:

```
BOOL isFileExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
NSAssert(isFileExist, @"filePath does not exist");
NSKeyedUnarchiver* coder =
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath]; // nil
NSData* data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];
coder = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; // nil
coder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data]; // OK!!!
```

<strike>It seems to be a bug in cocoa-touch.</strike>

**Edit:**

It is intended to behave like this and is not a bug. But I agree that the naming easily leads to mistakes.

`[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:]` returns a `NSKeyedUnarchiver` instance.

`[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]` returns the root object. It is a conviencen method for:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *coder = [[self alloc] initForReadingWithData:arg2];
id object = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"root"];
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You must always `-retain` an unarchived object: `Game *g2 = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath] retain];`
2. Does your `g2` conform to `NSCoding`? Make sure it does, if it doesn't declare `<NSCoding>` in the `g2` header. In the implementation file define methods `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` and `-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder`
3. If you're struggling to get this to work consider archiving and unarchiving a standard NSObject, like an NSString or some such. You probably don't need to archive a whole custom object, maybe just a remaining time number, game location or position or score. In other words, archive and unarchive the bare minimum you need.